# Sub-query select rows as columns (pivot)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT j.departure, stopDepartures.*
FROM journey j
JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = j.id
JOIN service ON service.id = j.service
JOIN pattern ON j.pattern = pattern.id
JOIN (
    SELECT section, pl.from_stop
    FROM pattern_link pl
    WHERE pl.section = section
) stopDepartures ON stopDepartures.section = pattern.section
WHERE service.id = "59924-44-X4-B-y10-2" AND journey_day.day = 1 AND pattern.direction = "outbound" AND DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN service.date_start AND service.date_end
GROUP BY j.id
ORDER BY departure ASC;
```

Currently, results for the above query will look something like:

```
`departure` | `section` | `from_stop`
    07:00    some_var_id  some_var_id
```

But the `stopDepartures` join is actually returning many `from_stop` fields for each `section`, but I will only ever see the first one. How can I change the `stopDepartures` join so that it acts like a pivot table, and returns each `from_stop` **as a column**? (Lots of columns, rather than 1 column for each first `from_stop` value)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this may do what you want.  Instead of:

```
SELECT j.departure, stopDepartures.*
```

Do:

```
SELECT j.departure, group_concat(from_stop)
```

This puts all the values in a comma-delimited list.  This is not a separate column for each one, but it may do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Gordon. Sadly I do need each stop in its own column, I have re-posted a clearer question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948622/mysql-pivot-style-row-column-results-in-subquery